# React не работает на IE8, что делать?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs

Пробовал добавлять скрипты как [предложено в документации](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#browser-support), пробовал добавлять код по [примеру из Github](https://github.com/xcatliu/react-ie8) в начало приложения:

```
require('es5-shim');
require('es5-shim/es5-sham');
require('console-polyfill');
```

Но ничего не помогает. Обычно появляется ошибка "Исключение брошено и не поймано" (Exception thrown and not caught).

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Какую версию react используете? Ну и неплохо было бы привести минимальный пример, приводящий к ошибке.

Comment: Какое исключение?

Comment: IE8 указывает на строку ' throw new TypeError '

Answer (score 1):

В общем, после такого кода, мне удалось что-то срендерить в IE8:
**App.js:**

```
require('core-js'); //Important!
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Application = React.createClass({ ... });
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Application,null), document.getElementById("app-container"));
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Используется html атрибут `defer`, чтобы задать очередность загрузки скриптов. 
Скрипты `es6-shim` и `es5-sham` загружаются первыми, а `bundle.js` после них из-за атрибута  `defer`

Comment: У вас тут es5-shim 2 раза подключен. А es6 нету

Comment: там es5-shim и es5-sham, а es6 я не использую в своем проекте